# Does the list of bugs which I found in the Oracle JDK give any benefits to my CV?

Tags: resume, career-development

This is more a specific question about particular career in Java-related development.

Say I have found a certain number of bugs in the various versions of the Oracle JDK (in compiler, specification and so on), of the priorities P3-P4 (they are admitted as bugs and were not closed as duplicates or "won't fix", so real issues).

I am curious, does it make any value in eyes of the potential employer?

In my opinion (as I have an experience of being a CTO for some period in my career in the past), I would certainly consider such a specialist as more valuable. But I am quite strange person with quite strange life vision, so may be I am wrong.

What do you think, is any sense put this list into the CV? Let's say we are talking about "Architect/Team lead" desired position.

Comment: VTC as primarily opinion based.  The combination of hiring manager opinions and different jobs makes this very speculative.  FWIW, if you were my architect, the last thing I want is you spending time digging into a failed third party api.

Comment: @cdkMoose Thanks God I am not *your* architect. Cause if you do not evaluate people's achievements in finding reasons about *why* certain things aren't working, if you call Oracle JDK as "3rd party API", and if you think that people's time is all *your* time, then after all ... I wouldn't be happy to work with you.

Comment: if your most recent job had you working at that low a level, I likely wouldn't consider you for an architect role and if you had been an architect, then I'm more concerned with what you did in that role than how many bugs you logged.  I would expect my team lead to tell a senior developer to go figure out why the specific code doesn't work.  Your time as a TL or architect is too valuable/costly to spend on that type of task.  I'd rather have my architect evaluating whether we should use Java or python or ..., not why some specific Java API has a bug in it.

Comment: with respect to "if you call Oracle JDK as "3rd party API"".  These questions are supposed to be answered in a way that is valuable to a broader audience, not just Java developers.  So, yes, I generalized that to 3rd party API.  .

Comment: @cdkMoose Okay, this *Your time as a TL or architect is too valuable/costly to spend on that type of task.* makes sense for me. However, does it mean that in your opinion that such sort of things should be omitted in the CV for these positions?

Comment: for a TL/Archtitect position, I would say yes.  But that's just my opinion, hence the VTC, because my opinion already disagrees with the opinion of your only answer and their is no right answer

Comment: @cdkMoose all things about career are subjective and opinion based. You can assert as 100% true and objective only answers on the statements of the sort like "Can I apply for TL position if I have just graduated from the school and don't know any programming languages" :-) This particular question might have, I would say, *statistical* sense. So if the mast majority consider these achievements as useless (like you do), then this is one case. Or, may be, otherwise: you are in the minority and most potential employers will evaluate such things.

Answer (score 3):

Certainly seems like an accomplishment to me. Shows you have troubleshooting skills, shows you know the product in depth and that you are able to work in an area that is possibly more complex (the bugs are not there in the most simple stuff).  Is this enough to get a team lead position? No but it might help to put you in the interview pile.

Comment: I know some companies put bounties out for finding bugs in their programs. If the OP ever got that or found a serious bug, then that is a huge plus.